# Whitespace in column name in Synapse

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

I am using Databricks to read data to a Spark Dataframe from Azure Synapse table.

```
df = spark.read \
          .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
          .option("url", sql_dw_connection_string) \
          .option("tempDir", temp_dir_url) \
          .option("enableServicePrincipalAuth", "true") \
          .option("query", query) \
          .load()
df.cache()
```

When I try to cache the Dataframe, I am getting the below error in Databricks.

```
    com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector. Make sure column names do not include any invalid characters such as ';' or whitespace
Underlying SQLException(s):
  - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Common.ExternalAccess.HdfsAccessException, Message: Error occurred while accessing HDFS external file[/sqldw-staging/2023-03-07/07-14-49-790/f030341a-12d7-4ae1-b5e0-81b510a9a9e1/QID68547779_20230307_71451_0.parq.snappy][0]: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_CreateRecordWriter. Java exception message:
HdfsBridge::createRecordWriter - Unexpected error encountered when creating a record writer: IllegalArgumentException: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'CODE' at line 9:   optional binary ATC CODE [ErrorCode = 110802] [SQLState = S0001]
```

The reason being is that in the Azure Synapse table have a column named `ATC CODE` where this column name have whitespace. I saw some solution in internet to replace whitespace with underscore but as per the project requirement, I am not suppose to replace whitespace with any other character.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/maintenance-updates), Invalid symbols like whitespace or semicolons are now returned by the Azure Synapse connection as an error when it found in a column name.

I also got similar error for column names `First Name` and `Last Name`.

[image]

- As you don't allow to change the column in database, to workaround this issue you can write a query to select column contain spaces as alias with underscore. Also you can create view for that and select that view in query.

```sql
select Id, [First Name] as First_name, [Last Name] as Last_name from demotb
```

then you will get column name with underscore in place of space as below:

[image]

- Then you can replace the `_`  with `space` by

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
renamed_df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(col.replace('_', ' ')) for col in df.columns])
```

[image]